# Magento 1.9.2 Pull Product Cost for Catalog Price Rule

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to create a Cost + Markup Catalog Price Rule, I've added the rule in the drop down, and created the statement to perform the calculation in:

```
/app/code/local/Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Action/Index/Refresh.php
```

At the moment I'm add the cost value manually to test the rule, and it's working correctly I now just need to be able to grab the product actual cost.

```
$toCost => new Zend_Db_Expr('3.79 * cppt.action_amount/100'),
```